# Module based project vs Normal project

Tags: oop, jakarta-ee, architecture, language-agnostic

I am writing code on top an established Enterprise application. I see that the application has 4 modules as shown below.

```
-Srk
-SrkEJB
-SrkUtils
-SrkWeb
```

I have gone through the code and I see that some modules are tiny for example: SrkEJB module has got just 2 EJBS. I don't see any reason to create a separate module for 2 Java classes.

I have simplified the above approach and is shown below.

```
Srk
 - com.srk.utils
 - com.srk.ejb
 - com.srk.web
```

How is the first module based architecture different from the second from an architectural stand point? Generally, which is the followed mostly, when creating an application from scratch? If not, What could be the trade-offs of each of the approaches? I believe this is a not specific to Java alone.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't see any reason to create a separate module for 2 Java classes.

I believe this is an invalid chain of reasoning. You should create a separate module whenever you discover classes, related to the same subject. The number of classes is irrelevant here. You may have a module containing only one class, if the purpose of that class is really different from others.

The name of the package / module should clearly speak its purpose. So, module name "Srk" seems bad to me (I suppose "srk" is some kind of abbreviated company name and is not related to architecture).

The same may be related to "utils", which sounds very generic to me. It is impossible to tell, what are those utils about.